# Force Solve to respect unit system

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, units

I give `Solve` quantities in FPS and it returns resulting quantities in SI, necessitating that I add an entire section to my workflow where I pick apart the solution lists and convert units.

From the documentation:

> `$UnitSystem` gives the unit system to assume for returned quantities.

`$UnitSystem` returns `Imperial`, but I have never seen Mathematica return imperial units by default.

Is there a graceful way to do this?

```
g = Quantity[32.2`, ("Feet")/("Seconds")^2];
Ws = Quantity[30, "PoundsForce"];
l = Quantity[2, "Feet"];
r = Quantity[1, "Feet"];

NSolve[
  Is == Ws/g (2/5 r^2 + (l + r)^2)
, Is]

Out= {{Is -> Quantity[..., "Kilograms" ("Meters")^2]}}
```

**Edit: solutions from the comments**

- Automatically convert output for the whole notebook:

  ```
  $Post = # /. q_Quantity -> UnitConvert[q, $UnitSystem] &;
  ```

  In my case I have `$Post` set so that the input `m = 5` results in the output `m = 5`; here then is an example of integrating this solution with an existing one:

  ```
  $Post = (# /. q_Quantity -> UnitConvert[q, $UnitSystem] &) /@ (
      If[ValueQ@lastSet, Row[{lastSet, " = ", #}], #] &
  );
  ```
- A workaround for one call to `Solve` that doesn't require treating each variable separately:

  ```
  sol = Solve[...]
  #[[1]] -> UnitConvert[#[[2]], $UnitSystem] & /@ (sol // Flatten)
  ```

  returns a list of rules similar to the original, but interferes with the nesting and may have issues with multiple solutions (untested).

Comment: I do not know why it does that. But you could always convert results to Imperial using `UnitConvert[sol, $UnitSystem]` each time?

Comment: Thanks I didn't know I could put $UnitSystem in like that. 
This works much better than what I had as far as a workaround goes: `#[[1]] -> UnitConvert[#[[2]], $UnitSystem] & /@ sol`

Comment: yes, but you can do it simpler than this. Just do `sol = Is /. First@Solve[Is == Ws/g (2/5 r^2 + (l + r)^2), Is];
sol = UnitConvert[sol, $UnitSystem]` This could be a bug why it does not return result automatically using `$UnitSystem`. But I do not use units myself. So I can't be sure. But it does look buggy behavior o me.

Comment: @Nasser that's similar to my original workaround, but I'm solving for 10-20 variables at a time so it's better to avoid the destructuring in `Is /. ...`

Comment: Use `$Post = # /. q_Quantity -> UnitConvert[q, $UnitSystem] &;` if you want all quantities to use `$UnitSystem`